# mirrored character 'splits' open when animating the body

Tags: mirror

I have seen one other post about this but the answer on that one didnt help me so sorry if I ask it again. I just started with blender and started rigging up my first character but i cant seem to connect my character half to the mirrored half which makes it split when moving bones.

[image: without moving any bones]
[image: when moving a bone]
[image]

Comment: hello, it's not clear what you mean by "i cant seem to connect my character half to the mirrored half", and it looks like you show the same picture twice

Comment: ok so I have fixed the pictures and what I meant with the halfs is seen on the last picture(the one with the vertices shown was the character half and the other one the mirrored half). And on the second picture you can see a gap at the belly area and that's my problem.